# Joomla Ajax request always return success

Tags: ajax, joomla

I'm trying to login in Joomla! by Ajax with default login module. But it always return success-

```
$('a.login_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $username = $('#username').val();
    $password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=login&method=user.login&format=json',
        data: {username: $username, password: $password},
        success: function(){
            $('.error').hide();
            $('.success').show();
        },
        error: function(){
            $('.success').hide();
            $('.error').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Why this always return true?

Comment: There is a stack exchange site just for Joomla, you will be better off asking there [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0):

It'll be always a success (provided you have a connection with a server). You must analyse the response on `success` to validate the credentials.

```
success: function(data){
    if ( data === "Correct" ) {                 
        //handle login                  
    }
    else {                  
        alert(data);                
    }               
}
```